# beamer: bibtex + natbib + hyperref, hyperlinks do not work

Tags: beamer, bibtex, hyperref, natbib

I want to use bibtex in a beamer presentation and format the citations with natbib. This code works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[super,sort,comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
year = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
Test \cite{author_book}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{References}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{mybib}{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But when I uncomment:

```
\usepackage[super,sort,comma]{natbib}
```

I get the citation format I want but the hyperlinks are lost. 
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

`hyperref` is loaded by the `beamer` class. At that stage `natbib` is not loaded, so `hyperref` does not activate its `natbib` compatibility code.  There is no easy way to turn that code on, a second loading of `hyperref` is simply ignored, and `beamer` messes with some of the same macros that `natbib` does.  (Incidentally using `natbib` you should use matching `\bibliographystyle` such as `plainnat`.)

If you want superscript citations with hyperlinks, then you can use `biblatex` with either its `\supercite` command or with a superscript option its `\autocite` command:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[autocite=superscript]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
year = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
Test \autocite{author_book}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The above code runs with `biber`; if you prefer `bibtex` then call the `biblatex` package as:

```
\usepackage[autocite=superscript,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```